# How can i Improve my code (Transaction took too long)

Tags: smart-contract, action

I have Enough CPU and NET
i have staked 13 EOS for each and still unable to run the code.
Please suggest if i can improve anything.
**IS there any problem of table index**

Got this from developer.io
if anyone can explain what is this **indexed_by<"byage"_n, const_mem_fun>** do
and **is there any mistake related to this in my code** coz i have not added this

```
typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, person, 
indexed_by<"byage"_n, const_mem_fun<person, uint64_t, &person
::get_secondary_1>>
  > address_index;
```

```
typedef eosio::multi_index<"paymentmade"_n,payment_made>paymentmade;    
paymentmade payMade_table;



void mainloan::payconfirm(double pay_amunt,name from ,uint64_t loan_id)
{
  require_auth(_self);
  auto loan = loan_table.find(loan_id);
  auto pay_date = current_time_point();

  paymade_table.emplace(get_self(),[&](auto &p){
  p.pay_id=paymade_table.available_primary_key();
  p.pay_date=pay_date;
  p.pay_amunt=pay_amunt;
  p.pay_from=from;
  p.loan_id=loan_id;
}); 
loan_table.modify(loan, _self,[&](auto& l){
  l.last_pay_date = pay_date;
  l.lending_amount=loan->lending_amount-pay_amunt; 
});
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on your local computer? If so the issue is probably that your CPU is too slow

Comment: yes, its local computer.Is there anything i can do to make it work ?

Comment: Your code can't really be optimised much further, the problem is your computer isn't fast enough to run the code. Without buying a better computer, all you can do is make sure that you run as few processes alongside nodeos as possible

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything fancy, what is your `max-transaction-time` set at in your `config.ini` file for your nodeos instance?  You may be able to resolve the issue by upping it.

Comment: EOSIO testnet can be ran locally on a potato. Increase max transaction time as suggested.